# use weka with java for prediction on test set

Tags: java, weka, predict

I am trying to get the predictions on test set using evaluateModel function, however `evaluation.evaluateModel(classifier, newTest,output)`   throws an exception.

> Exception in thread "main" weka.core.WekaException: No dataset
>   structure provided!

```
        import weka.classifiers.Evaluation;
        import weka.core.Attribute;
        import weka.core.Instances;
        import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource;
        import weka.classifiers.Evaluation;
        import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource;
        import weka.attributeSelection.CfsSubsetEval;
        import weka.attributeSelection.ASSearch;
        import weka.attributeSelection.BestFirst;
        import weka.classifiers.functions.LinearRegression;
        import weka.classifiers.meta.AttributeSelectedClassifier;
        import weka.filters.supervised.attribute.AttributeSelection;
        import weka.classifiers.evaluation.output.prediction.CSV;


        public void evaluateTest() throws Exception
  {
        DataSource train = new DataSource(trainingData.toString());
        Instances traininstances = train.getDataSet();
        Attribute attr=traininstances.attribute("regressionLabel");
        int trainindex=attr.index();
        traininstances.setClassIndex(trainindex); 

        DataSource test = new DataSource(testData.toString());
        Instances testinstances = test.getDataSet();
        Attribute testattr=testinstances.attribute(regressionLabel);
        int testindex=testattr.index();
        testinstances.setClassIndex(testindex); 


        AttributeSelection filter = new AttributeSelection();
        weka.classifiers.AbstractClassifier classifier ;
        filter.setSearch(this.search);
        filter.setEvaluator(this.eval);
        filter.setInputFormat(traininstances);  // initializing the filter once with training set
        Instances newTrain = AttributeSelection.useFilter( traininstances, filter);  // configures the Filter based on train instances and returns filtered instances
        Instances newTest = AttributeSelection.useFilter(testinstances, filter);          
        classifier= new LinearRegression();

        classifier.buildClassifier(newTrain);

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        CSV output = new CSV();
        output.setBuffer(buffer);
        output.setOutputFile(predictFile);

        Evaluation evaluation = new Evaluation(newTrain);
        evaluation.evaluateModel(classifier, newTest,output);
}
```

The same thing works with  `evaluation.crossValidateModel`.

Comment: Where are your `trainingData` from?

Comment: Its a csv file with feature values and regression label. Also, if I use evaluation.evaluateModel(classifier, newTest); evaluation.toSummaryString()  ;                                                                        get the  the correct output but I am not able to write predicted values to a csv file.

Comment: Sry for misunderstanding me. I meant, where is the Varaible `trainingData` set? Because your first line ist  `DataSource train = new DataSource(trainingData.toString());`

Comment: It contains the complete path of the csv file as a File object  and is passed as a parameter in the function.

Comment: i cannot see any problems with your code, but only the `trainingData`and the `testData`variables. If there is no file and right data behind you will got the Exception in this line `classifier.buildClassifier(newTrain);`

Comment: I had similar issues. Problem is that weka struggles with special characters spaces etc. Then it would see that no of columns are not matching and thus shows its inability to understand data structure of the file.

I would reccommend you to clean your data and then test again..

Comment: But I get correct output values such as regression coefficient etc if I modify               evaluation.evaluateModel(classifier, newTest,output);
                                                                                                                               to evaluation.evaluateModel(classifier, newTest);                                                  Do I need to specify any structure for  predictFile. Its just a File object containing the pathname of file to write predicted values.